# Show by definition that $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

> Show **by definition**  that the function $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ defined by $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{x} & 0<x<1\\3 & x=0\\5 & x=1\end{cases}$$is measurable.

Let  $\alpha$ be any real number. Then

$$\{f>\alpha\}=\begin{cases} [0,1] & \alpha<1 \\ [0,1/\alpha] &\alpha\ge 1 \end{cases}$$
Please check my calculation and detect if something wrong there. Also comment if there are no mistake.

Comment: Why did you choose $\alpha$ in those intervals?  What is so special about $0.1$?  I think your calculation for $\alpha > 1$ is wrong.  For example, take $\alpha = 1.1$.  Then we want to find the $x$ such that $f(x) > 1.1$.  But $x = \frac{1}{2}$ satisfies this inequality since $f(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{(\frac{1}{2})} = 2 > 1.1$.

Comment: No, if $\alpha > 1,$ then $\{f>\alpha\}$ contains $ (0,1/\alpha).$

Comment: @zhw. & @user46944)  Am I right now? Please see and verify the edit.

Comment: If you want to *show-by-definition*, you should provide the $\sigma$-algebra. Your question would be 'how to make $f$ measureable'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your calculations are still not correct ... since this exercise is not *that* difficult, this makes me believe that you don't really know what you are doing.

In order to show measurability of $f$, we have to show that the preimages

$$\{f>\alpha\} := \{x \in [0,1]; f(x)>\alpha\}$$

are Borel sets for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. To get some first intuition how these sets look like, it is a good idea to draw a picture.

[image]

For each fixed $\alpha$ we have to find the points $x \in [0,1]$ such that the value $f(x)$ is (stricly) above the green line; above you see pictures for $\alpha=2$ and $\alpha=4$.

- **Case 1: $\alpha<1$.** Since $f(x) \geq 1>\alpha$ for any $x \in [0,1]$ we have $$\{f>\alpha\} = [0,1]$$ for any $\alpha<1$, this agrees with your calculation.
- **Case 2: $\alpha \in [1,3)$.** Using the monotonicity of $f$ on $(0,1)$ and the fact that $f(0)=3 >\alpha$ and $f(1)=5>\alpha$, we find $$\{f>\alpha\} = (0,\alpha^{-1}) \cup \{0\} \cup \{1\}$$ for $\alpha \in [1,3)$.
- **Case 3: $\alpha \in [3,5)$.** Note that $f(0) = 3 < \alpha$ and therefore $0 \notin \{f>\alpha\}$. Again the monotonicity on $(0,1)$ and the fact that $f(0)=5>\alpha$ yields $$\{f>\alpha\} = (0,\alpha^{-1}) \cup \{1\}.$$
- **Case 4: $\alpha \geq 5$.** For any such $\alpha$, we have $\{f>\alpha\} = (0,\alpha^{-1})$.

Since $(0,\alpha^{-1})$, $\{0\}$, $\{1\}$ are Borel sets, this shows that $f$ is (Borel)measurable.